# How to call URL containing non latin characters using cURL and PHP?

Tags: php, curl, encoding, character-encoding

I am reading data from excel file using [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) with this settings:

```
$data->setOutputEncoding('CP1250');
```

I am iterating through cells and rows and I am building URL for each row containing its data. After that I am visiting this URL with cURL. Here is the code:

```
$h = fopen("cookies.txt", "w");
$header=array('GET /1575051 HTTP/1.1',
    'Host: asd.pl',
    'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language:pl-Pl,pl;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
    'Connection:keep-alive',
    'Host:google.pl',
    'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36',
    );
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    //file_put_contents("dane.txt",curl_exec($ch)."\n", FILE_APPEND);
fclose($h);
 curl_close($ch);
```

When script visits generated URL, other server is saving data from `GET` to database. I have `utf8_general_ci` encoding there.

After the save Polish (non Latin) characters are missing; but, when I echo the URLs and visit them manually it's OK. Is the problem encoding of the cURL's header? I tried setting it to various types and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Pass the encoding on the headers `$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; `

Comment: Nothing changed, I also tried with ISO-8859-2, and also no resutls.

Comment: Can you post the response header/body from the curl request. I'm assuming you passed the correct charset on the header.

Comment: FYI, I didn't solve the problem, I found a workaround though. I imported the file into database and worked with this.